# Importing excel files into Wordpress custom post

Tags: wordpress, excel

I'm starting work on a new Jobs website (where client can create new jobs through the WP backend). This is easy enough with setting up with a custom plugin like post-meta

Wordpress - post meta plugin

Which I've setup with custom post meta fields (location, sector, status etc.)

However when I create jobs and fill out the post meta fields and check the DB they all have array encoding:

E.g. a:1:{i:1;a:1:{i:1;a:1:{i:0;s:11:"Sydney City";}}}

How do I remove this so it simply says 'Sydney City' for the meta key value?

But even if I fix that, the client needs to send me a spreadsheet with all the jobs, how do I import something like that into the DB? For example how can a spreadsheet like this:

Job Name,Advertiser,Status,Start,Finish,Category,Suburb,State
Value 1,Hays Constr,Tender,12/3/13,12/4/14,....

Be imported into the meta_key, meta_value architecture? Is it even possible?

What do you think would be the way to proceed? I do want the client to be able to edit Jobs in the WP Admin... but I also need to import a ton of jobs and surely there's a quicker way to do this

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Research this site on how to read Excel/CSV with PHP. After that, you'll have to [make a plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=frequent&pageSize=50). Right now, I'm voting to close this as *too-broad* (see [help/on-topic]).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php you can use `unserialise` php function to get specific values in your serialise data

Comment: and even importing as csv is possible if you cant do it yourself. you can go for plugins there are many available on wordpress repositery

Comment: This is a test I did to [export Comments to Excel, using PHPExcel](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/6789233).